# How can I change a user's password from the command line using Drush?

Tags: users, drush

How can I change a user's password from the command line using Drush?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In Drush 9, the command is [`drush user:password USERNAME "SOMEPASSWORD"`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:password/); its aliases are *user-password* and *upwd*.

In Drush 8 (and earlier) the command is [`drush user-password USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-password/); its alias is *upwd*.

Comment: Instead of username, you could also use the user id: `drush upwd 1 --password="newpassword"` for user 1

Answer (score 35):

You can execute `drush uli`, this will generate a one time login link.
By default it provides one-time login link for administrator.

If you execute `drush uli some-username`, this will generate one time login link for that user.

**UPDATE:**

You can also use `drush upwd` for updating the password. Use it like this `drush upwd --password=<new password> <some-username>`

Comment: Worth noting that drush uli should be the preferred route in general from a good security practice POV because it means you do not have to communicate the password, the user can choose their own.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Drush 4, you can use the user-password command.

```
drush user-password usernamehere --password="newpasswordhere"
```

Answer (score 14):

> $ drush help user-password
>   (Re)Set the password for the user account with the specified name.
>
> Examples: drush user-password someuser --password="correct horse battery"
>   Set the password for the username someuser. @see xkcd.com/936
>
> Arguments:  name The name of the account to modify.
>
> Options:  --password=  The new password for the account. Required.
>
> Aliases: upwd

Answer (score 14):

In Drush 9 (recommended for > Drupal 8.4) this is slightly different:

```
drush upwd USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to reset password. You can use `drush uli "username"` which gives reset link in terminal, using the link you can login and change the password.

If you specify `-l http://localhost` (where localhost is your host), then terminal would automatically open web browser for you.

Comment: This works, but you may need Drupal 7.50 (released 2016-07-07) to not run into [issue 889772](https://www.drupal.org/node/889772) ("needing password to change password").

Answer (score 4):

in New version of Drush(In Drush 9 Drupal > 8.5 ) it doesn't work with

```
drush user-password USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"
```

**It must be**

```
drush user-password USERNAME SOMEPASSWORD
```

for example ( change password of root user)

```
drush user-password root MyPass0302
```

And with [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/)

```
drupal user:password:reset
```

then enter userid,
then type new password.

Enjoy it.

**Update**

in Drush > 9

```
drush upwd USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have ssh access to the server, cd to the drupal root directory and run:

`drush upwd --password="myNewSecretPassword" "admin"`

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/44164

Answer (score 1):

Note that this command has changed in Drush 9.x, but can be found documented [here](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:password/)

The syntax thus looks like this:

```
drush user:password someuser "correct horse battery staple"
```

For example, on the user 'bjenkins' it would be:

```
drush user:password bjenkins "newReallyComplexPassword123!"
```

You can also add a `--notify` command to notify the user of this password change to their registered email.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can generate the query and run it in your Drupal Database then the password will be reset http://btobac.com/reset-drupal-admin-password-mysql-query-phpmyadmin