# How do I change the admin password form PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: 7

How do I change the admin password form PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Some guesses what the question might be: (1) you want to change something in a **form** (as in your title). (2) you somewhere have a password for an admin, and you want to change it from "phpmyadmin" to "Drupal. (3) You wonder how you can use Drupal to change the Admin password to logon to PhpMyAdmin (4) you want to change some Drupal Admin password from within PhpMyAdmin. Or still something else? BTW: do you have Drush installed?

Comment: get the query from here and run in phpmyadmin http://btobac.com/reset-drupal-admin-password-mysql-query-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

if you have the drush installed in your system . You can use the below command :

```
drush user-password USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"
```

For more reference [refer this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-change-a-users-drupal-password-with-drush)

Answer (score 0):

You can change with going to users table

1 Run query

```
`UPDATE users SET name='admin', pass='$S$Drl0vgZ9yuU9uc4JyaTMHxMPriC7q/PsOUOx52fCrVQSTpI/Tu4x' WHERE uid = 1;`
```

1. change email address in users table   getting the password reset link (only applicable for if password is foget )
   checkout this [link](https://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/different-ways-reset-drupal-admin-password) for more information

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin run this query.Then your username is "admin" and password is "admin".

```
   'UPDATE users SET name='admin', pass='$S$DUW/9/iT3a6vAzdFrjsXki9IHC.CjgW4yrsZlDTzMlKXdd5Wk.mb' WHERE uid = 1;'
```

Answer (score 0):

By using drush you can do like this:

> drush uli or drush uli uid

drush uli provides link like this for admin(by default)

http://default/user/reset/1/1470735542/FAG2Elp2J_eN4k6XMq_KleQmBTmQ1Uoitl0Vs86JvdA
Replace default with your site URL.

Refer this [link](https://randyfay.com/content/resetting-drupal-passwords-drupal-7-drush-or-without).